# FIFO tie breaker in Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

For a homework, I need to compare Nodes based on a heuristic so that I can put them in a TreeSet. However, when the heuristic values for two Nodes are equal I need some way to break the tie.

I'm not allowed to modify the Node class provided and as far as I can tell there aren't any other values / properties of Node that would help me break the tie that I'm not already using. (We're dealing with puzzles, not that it really matters.) Is there some way I could break ties based on when I added them to my TreeSet? I just don't know how to go about it....

I saw an example in the documentation for a Priority Blocking Queue but I want to use the Comparator interface, and I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance; any tips / hints are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to create a wrapper for Nodes?

```
public class NodeWrapper implements Comparable<NodeWrapper> {
  private static AtomicLong serialNumGenerator = new AtomicLong(0L);

  private final Node node;
  private final long serialNum;

  public NodeWrapper(Node node) {
    this.node = node;
    this.serialNum = serialNumGenerator.getAndIncrement();
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(NodeWrapper other) {
    int compare = this.node.compareTo(other.node);
    if (compare == 0) {
      compare = (this.serialNum < other.serialNum)
          ? -1
          : ((this.serialNum > other.serialNum) ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return compare;
  }
  // implement other methods including equals() and hashCode()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [System.identityHashCode(Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) to get an int that you can use to sort the objects.

Comment: This will *probably* work in practice, but it's permissible for non-identical instances to return the same value here. In fact if you have 2^32 + 1 nodes, it's guaranteed that two non-identical nodes will have the same identity hash code.